# Not able to install shapely

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, shapely

I have been trying to install shapely on my Linux manjaro laptop but without success. All the commands I have used always end in my laptop freezing. 
I have used: 
conda install shapely
conda install -c conda-forge shapely 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 shapely 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 shapely

Please help.

Comment: Hey Alberta, Please also specify what errors you got when you run the above commands.

Comment: It says, “solving environment” and goes on to freeze 

Comment: Does it happen only with Shapely or with any other packages? Did you try to update conda/wait more time/run with sudo? There are some issues on GitHub about freezes on "solving environment", maybe you will find something helpful there: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8051, https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8197

Comment: I installed shapely with sudo and it worked, but it didn’t with anaconda. Okay I’ll check he link. Thank you! :)